Defining Sample Space for Stochastic Processes
I am studying stochastic processes and am struggling to understand how these processes can be properly defined.
Consider the following experiment: I toss a coin, and if it lands on tails, I lose $1$. If it lands on heads, I win $1$. Let $X_i$ be a random variable representing the sum after $i$ coin tosses. Thus, $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a stochastic process. This experiment can be modeled as $\{H, T\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.
However, if we take $\Omega = \{H, T\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and consider an event $\omega \in \Omega$, it doesn't make sense to talk about $X_1(\omega)$ since $X_1$ is the result after one toss and not an infinite number of tosses. $X_1$ is only defined on $\{H, T\}$, not on $\Omega$.
Therefore, looking at the sample path $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ doesn't make much sense in this case, since the $X_i$ are not defined for $\omega$.
Hence my question: How is the sample space defined so that every $X_i$ is well-defined and the notion of a sample path makes sense?

You could let $X_i=Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_i$, where $Y_j(\omega)=Z(\omega_j)$ for any $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,...)\in\Omega= {H,T}^{\Bbb N}$, with $Z(H)=1, Z(T)=-1$.

The sample space $\Omega= \{H,T\}^{\Bbb N}$ already allows the appropriate definition of the random variables $X_i:\Omega\to\Bbb N$ for $i=1,2,3,...$
Just let  $X_i=Y_1+Y_2+\ldots+Y_i$, where $Y_j(\omega)=Z(\omega_j)$ for any $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,...)\in\Omega$, with $Z(H)=1, Z(T)=-1$.
In other words, $X_i(\omega)=X_i(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots):=Z(\omega_1)+Z(\omega_2)+\ldots+Z(\omega_i)$. This can also be written $X_i=Z\circ\text{proj}_1+Z\circ\text{proj}_2+\ldots+Z\circ\text{proj}_i$, where $\text{proj}_j(\omega)=\omega_j$ is the $j$th "coordinate" (projection) of $\omega$.
Note: Calling each toss a "trial", let the "single trial" sample space be $S$ (here it's $\{H,T\}$). If $A_i\subseteq S$ is some event on the $i$th trial, $i=1,...,n$, then using the infinite Cartesian product
$$A_1\times\cdots\times A_n\times S\times S\times\cdots\subseteq S^{\Bbb N}=\Omega$$
to represent the finite Cartesian product
$$A_1\times\cdots\times A_n\subseteq S^{n}$$
is somewhat analogous to using infinitely many $0$s in the representation of a terminating binary numeral; e.g., $0.1101000...=0.1101$. (But unlike such numerals, these representations are unique!)
